# file_put_content in xslt-1.0

Tags: php, xslt-1.0

the question is, is there an other (better) way to implement the thing i did.

What I was trying is, to make a XSLT to write a file onto the server where the XSLT is running.

> Note: It has to be XSLT-1.0 cause it is called by a PHP scrip.
>
> The PHP script is running on a local server and is called from a java program

The XSLT generates a message send back to the java program, so i can't use `<xsl:output method="xml"/>`

Input in my XSLT is a XML, and within it, there is an other XML, which is base64 encoded.

My approach to this Problem is, that I am using a PHP-call-back

**XLST**

```
<!--base64 decode the file so it can be written onto the server-->
<xsl:variable name="base64decode">
   <xsl:if test="not(contains($login ,'Invalid')))">
       <xsl:value-of select="php:function('base64_decode', string($product))"/>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>

<!--php call-back to write the file onto the server-->
<xsl:variable name="fileputcontent">
    <xsl:if test="$base64decode != ''">
        <xsl:value-of select="php:function('postProduct::wirteFileOnServer', string($base64decode))"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

**PHP**

```
class postProduct {

    public static function writeFileOnServer($file, $path){
        file_put_contents($path, $file);
        $ret = new DOMDocument('1.1', 'UTF-8');

        if(not(is_file($path))){
            $res = '<error>';
            $res.= '<msg>An Error occurred</msg>';
            $res.= '</error>';
        }
        $res = '<data>'.$res.'</data>';
        $res = $ret->loadXML($res, LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
        if ($res !== TRUE) {
            $ret->appendChild($err);
        }
        return $ret;
    }

}
```